# Django post form fields to another page

Tags: django, post, django-views, django-forms, get

I have a Django form that takes filter options for a report.  The report page is a separate view that renders the report based on the form data.

My first pass at this, I simply set the action of the form to the report page and method to GET.  The form data was then passed directly the report view via the querystring which I would use GET to retrieve.  The problem with this was that this bypassed form validation since the the form did not post back to its own view.

My next pass, I removed the form action (so it would post back to itself) and used form_valid (I am using class based views) to encode the form data and redirect to the report view like so:

```
ReportOptionsView(FormView)
    form_class = OptionsForm
    template_name = 'my_report_options.html'
    report = reverse_lazy('my_report')
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        qstr = urlencode(form.cleaned_data)
        return redirect(self.report+"?"+qstr)
```

The report page works the same -I just retrieve the information from the querystring to filter the models and display the report.

I would prefer the form data not appear on the querystring of the report page.  When I tried to redirect to the report page using a POST method is where I starting having trouble. Even going back to my original flow setting the form action to the report page (thus losing validation) and setting the form method to POST, I got 405 errors.  I realize that there may be ways to do this using Javascript, but would prefer to stick with Django/Python

My question is, what is the proper method in Django to take cleaned data from a validated form and POST that data to separate view so that the form data is not exposed in the URL?

Comment: You should probably use the session storage for this. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/. Also, maybe the use of form wizard might be more suitable for this (https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html).

Comment: Thank you - yes, session storage should work for my situation if there is no way in Django for a form to POST to a separate view.  I suspect using the form Wizard, that final step (... or whatever the application needs to do.) will be subject to the same limitation I am having with a single form...